# Library defined but no canonical name

Tags: autotools, automake

I'm trying to build a project using autotools and getting this error:

```
$ autoreconf --install
automake: warnings are treated as errors
src/Makefile.am:3: warning: variable 'librombrowser_a_LDFLAGS' is defined but no program or
src/Makefile.am:3: library has 'librombrowser_a' as canonical name (possible typo)
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

the src/Makefile.am is following:

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = librombrowser.a
librombrowser_a_CPPFLAGS = $(GTK_CFLAGS)
librombrowser_a_LDFLAGS = $(GTK_LIBS)
librombrowser_a_SOURCES =                                                      \
                          rombrowser-app.c                                     \
                          rombrowser-app.h                                     \
                          rombrowser-cmds-file.c                               \
                          rombrowser-cmds-help.c                               \
                          rombrowser-cmds.h                                    \
                          rombrowser-dirs.c                                    \
                          rombrowser-dirs.h                                    \
                          rombrowser-settings.c                                \
                          rombrowser-settings.h

bin_PROGRAMS = rombrowser
rombrowser_SOURCES = rombrowser.c
rombrowser_LDADD = librombrowser
```

I'm not seeing what's wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_LDFLAGS` isn't valid for a static library, only for an executable or a shared library.  You may want `_LIBADD` instead.  It seems to me that the error message could be improved.

Comment: Indeed, the error message is more instructive if you try to use `_LDADD`: `error: use 'lib<name>_la_LIBADD', not 'lib<name>_la_LDADD'`.